# Curious badge still stuck

Tags: support

I now have 5 positive questions on five separate days (and I received no downvoted questions on at least 5 of these days). I have an positive overall question record. Why is the badge still stuck? :~?

Do I have to do [some sort of pig ritual](http://www.vox.com/2015/9/21/9365507/piggate-david-cameron-piers-galverston) to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, badges are checked as part of a periodic maintenance routine.

The fifth day where you have asked a positive question was today.  Your badge isn't going to show up the second you ask the fifth question, it will be applied when maintenance happens.

Additionally, as per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256469/curious-badge-bug/256477#256477) you need a positive question record, which apparently, you don't.  Negative, closed, and deleted questions count against you, and if question is negatively voted, closed and deleted, it negates **3** good answers.

You might also be interested to know that you can actually track the badge's progress from your profile.  See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263353/181798) for more info on what this looks like.

Comment: So a deleted downvoted question is worse than one which remains available. That would make more sense of things if it's true, as otherwise it would seem I should have a very positive question record.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter-Poulsen  according to the answer i linked to, a deleted downvoted question counts against you twice

Comment: One might also think the arcane workings of this badge were designed to make you curious about it's nature...